# Ethernet Basics - Switch Fabric, Managed Ethernet Switch & Virtual PHY terminology

Tags: switch, ethernet, management

I'm a new member to this community.

I've just started to learn and practice on working with LAN Ethernet PHYs, Switches and other ICs related to Ethernet.

However, I've a few questions where I couldn't understand some terms.

Can someone please explain me on what the terms mean:

"Managed Ethernet Switch" - What is being managed?

"Switch Fabric"

"Virtual PHY"

"Peer to Peer transparent clocks"

I was going through the datasheet of this - [IC](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/LAN9353)

Please do help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A *managed* Ethernet switch provides some kinds of management and configuration - e.g. bandwidth measurement, error counters, SNMP, VLAN and port configuration. See [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch#Typical_management_features) for more.
- A *switch fabric* is a concept for building hardware switches - it alludes to the basic property that each port can talk to any other (idle) port at the same time. You can visualize that as a fabric of connections inside the switch (although it's not usually implemented like that).
- The *virtual PHY* is described in the text (an actually PHY-less connection to the host, using an MII).
- *Transparent clocks* refers to PTP/IEEE 1588 synchronized clocks.

Comment: Could you please provide some more explanation on the 3 point of Virtual PHY? What is the advantage?

Comment: A direct MII-to-MII connection skips the two PHYs in between for backplane-type connections. It's just a bit less hardware for the same functionality.